# Cómo pasar parametros con ELOQUENT y filtrar contenido según parámetro

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo el siguiente enlace:

```
{{ url('/encuestas') }}
```

Que tiene que tener una categoría como parámetro por ejemplo:

```
{{ url('/encuestas/casa') }}
```

En el controlador debería llegar esa categoria como parámetro para filtrar las preguntas de la base de datos:

```
  public function index(categoria $categoria)
        {
        $preguntas=Pregunta::all();
          ->where('categoria', '=',$categoria);

        return view("encuesta", compact("preguntas"));

        }
```

Devuelve un error:

> "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table"

Comment: pues tienes un ->where saliendo de la nada

Comment: Como te mencionan ese `where` esta encadenado a nada, creo debería verse así: `$preguntas=Pregunta::all()->where('categoria', '=',$categoria);`

Comment: Que de hecho esa consulta pudiera quedar así: `$preguntas = Pregunta::where('categoria', $categoria)->get();`

Comment: @Aprendiz la segunda opción que pones creo que sería la mas eficiente, pues segun entiendo, `all()` va a ejecutar la consulta y traer todos los datos de la tabla para luego hacer el `where()` sobre la colección resultante. En cambio con `get()` la consulta traería solo los datos que coincidan con el `where()`. Si la tabla tiene muuchas filas, se notaría la diferencia.

Comment: Estoy probando, parece que tiene buena pinta, pero ¿El enlace debería ser {{ url('/encuestas/casa') }} por ejemplo? ¿O debería ser {{ url('/encuestas?categoria=casa') }} para que coja el parámetro el enlace?

Comment: Si pongo: {{ url('/encuestas',['categoria' => 'casa']) }} devuelve error: doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `encuestas` where `id` = casa limit 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::any('/encuestas/{filtro}','Controlador@index');


public function index($filtro){
    $preguntas=Pregunta::where('categoria',$filtro)->get();

    return view("encuesta", compact("preguntas"));

}
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto! Gracias Mr.Suk y Aprendiz! ; )

Answer (score 1):

- Inicialmente el error parece indicar que Eloquent no puede empatar el nombre del modelo `Pregunta` con una tabla en plural `preguntas` ya que el nombre pudiera ser distinto de esa convención
- Si la tabla posee un nombre distintos, en el modelo `Pregunta` deberás tener una propiedad protegida con el nombre de la misma así:

Código

```
protected $table = "nombreTabla";
```

Siguiente:

La consulta debería ser de este modo:

```
$preguntas = Pregunta::where('categoria', $categoria)->get();
```

O así:

```
$preguntas = Pregunta::whereCategoria($categoria)->get();
```

Ya que usas `all()` pero este método esta destinado para:

> Retornar todos los registros de la tabla asociada al modelo en cuestión

Entonces si tu intención es filtrar la data entonces solo deja el modelo y accede al método `where()` para indicar la condición a cumplir y extraer los datos necesarios.

**Referencias**

- [Definición de modelos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models)
- [Retornando modelos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models)

Comment: ¿El enlace a esa consulta debería ser algo así como {{ url('/encuestas',['categoria' => 'casa']) }} ? Gracias.

Comment: Dame unos minutos y te respondo

Comment: Claro. Gracias Aprendiz.

Comment: en tu archivo web.php, ¿cómo esta definida la ruta a la que deseas apuntar? @alderson

Comment: en web tengo: Route::resource('/encuestas','EncuestaController'); Con la url: {{ url('/encuestas') }} me va bien pero sin hacer la consulta. Sin parámetro.

Comment: ahora dime a que método estás apuntando? es decir al método show, create. update, edit?

Comment: al método index

Comment: Prueba así: `{{ route('encuestas', $categoria->casa) }}`

Comment: Gracias pero me devuelve "Undefined variable: categoria" en la misma página donde está la url sin pulsarla. Se supone que creas el parámetro que quieras ahí mismo. No? O hay que definir el parámetro en web.php